# ActivatedRoute does not contain any params from auxilary route

Tags: angular

When user clicks the edit button, I change the url to `/posts/(modal:1/edit) which displays a modal dialog. I need to access the query params of that route to get the id of the post. Params are always an empty object. Whenever I look through the browser console. I see`Router Event: ActivationEnd` three different times. The first and last time the params object is empty however the second time it has the value I need.

Why is `Router Event: ActivationEnd` displayed so many times?

Running `ngOnInit` logs only once, meaning that the component is mounted only once.

Any ideas?

This is how I am changing the route

```
`
this.router.navigate([{outlets: {modal: `${this.post.postID}/edit`}}], {relativeTo: this.route});
`
```

here are my routes:

```
`
{ path: 'new', component: PostItDialogContainerComponent, outlet: 'modal' },
    { path: ':id/edit', component: PostItDialogContainerComponent, outlet: 'modal' }, 
`
```

`PostItDialogContainerComponent` just makes a call to the `DialogService` to open up the modal

```
`
ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Inside of post it dialog container");
    this.postItDialog.openPostItDialog(this.dialog);
  }
`
```

My router-outlets are on the same `app.component.html` level

```
`
<main>
              <router-outlet></router-outlet>              
              <router-outlet name="modal"></router-outlet>
            </main>
`
```

This is the modal dialog in `ngOnInit`:

```
`
this.route.params
      .subscribe(
        (params) => {
          this.postID = params['id'];
            this.params = params;
            this.editMode = params['id'] != null;
            this.initForm();
            console.log("PARAMS ID IS: ", params['id']);                  
        }
      );
`
```

I know I'm missing something here, but I cant pin point it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe try moving the `:id` onto the main route so that your url looks something like this: `/posts/1(modal:edit)`

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being more convoluted than I had hoped, but this was the only way I could get the params of the auxiliary route. All other calls to this.route.params.subscribe() kept coming up as empty objects.

in ngOnInit I have the following code:

```
`
this.route.firstChild
      .children
      .filter(routes => routes.outlet == 'modal')
      .map(r => r.params.subscribe(
        (params) => {
          this.editMode = params['id'] != null
          this.postID = +params['id']
        }
      ))
`
```

this will look at the ActivatedRoute and then check its firstChild ActivatedRoute and then check for any children that have the outlet of 'modal'. Then we map each ActivatedRoute and subscribe to their params to retrieve the id and the mode.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as expected when you inject ActivatedRoute in the component to which the auxiliary route points (your code snippets do not reveal which instance of ActivatedRoute you have used.)

**Explanation:**

ActivatedRoute is not a global singleton, and components from different RouterOutlets will receive different instances of ActivatedRoute, depending on 'their' route, even when displayed concurrently. In particular, params from child routes are not visible in the ActivatedRoute of their parent components (which makes sense: a parent could have more than one nested outlet, which opens the possibility of auxiliary param name collision).

So to get params from an auxiliary route, you need to look at the ActivatedRoute instance injected in the auxiliary route's component. If you need to propagate the value back to the parent component, you probably have to do this by hand (e.g. via a shared service).